# Can we write to multiple hive tables based on the input events from a single kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, hive, spark-streaming

I have a scenario where im producing message from Oracle Db to kafka topic

Now I’m consuming the messages from kafka using Java-Spark and I want to write it to respective hive tables based on the events consumed

Say there are two tables where the message is received in kafka:

```
Table 1 has received 1 event 
Table 2 has received 2events
```

Now I want write :

```
table1.event —> hive.table1 (1event)
Table2.event —> hive.table2(2 events)
```

I knew if have multiple topics we can implement it but here i have only one topic and write to hive table based on its conditions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use filter operator of Structured Streaming to create distinct dataframes which can be individually written to other locations